# ValueError: can't read cfg files (sense2vec, reddit vectors)

Tags: valueerror, sense2vec

I am relatively new to NLP and mostly use Jupyter, please let me know what I'm doing wrong:

I followed all the instructions provided here:

https://github.com/explosion/sense2vec

but when I try to use the reddit_vectors as described here:

```
s2v = Sense2VecComponent(nlp.vocab).from_disk("/path/to/s2v_reddit_2015_md")
```

I get a ValueError as shown below:

```
    ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-36-0d396d0145de> in <module>
----> 1 s2v=Sense2Vec().from_disk('reddit_vectors-1.1.0/vectors.bin/')

~/.conda/envs/NewEnv6/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sense2vec/sense2vec.py in from_disk(self, path, 
exclude)
    343         cache_path = path / "cache"
    344         self.vectors = Vectors().from_disk(path)
--> 345         self.cfg.update(srsly.read_json(path / "cfg"))
    346         if freqs_path.exists():
    347             self.freqs = dict(srsly.read_json(freqs_path))

~/.conda/envs/NewEnv6/lib/python3.7/site-packages/srsly/_json_api.py in read_json(location)
     48         data = sys.stdin.read()
     49         return ujson.loads(data)
---> 50     file_path = force_path(location)
     51     with file_path.open("r", encoding="utf8") as f:
     52         return ujson.load(f)

~/.conda/envs/NewEnv6/lib/python3.7/site-packages/srsly/util.py in force_path(location, 
require_exists)
     19         location = Path(location)
     20     if require_exists and not location.exists():
---> 21         raise ValueError("Can't read file: {}".format(location))
     22     return location
     23
```

ValueError: Can't read file: reddit_vectors-1.1.0/vectors.bin/cfg

*I installed all the appropriate versions of libraries/packages required in the requirements.txt

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:

1. If you are not using a virtual environment check if all the libraries from  libraries/packages required in the requirements.txt actually got installed properly, in my case one of them was not properly installed.
2. The path should lead to the folder containing the cfg file. (After the last update I recommend using the entire computer path instead of navigating inside the same project)

Answer (score 0):

1. Check your path to reddit_vectors-x.x.x folder. 
   Put your reddit_vectors-x.x.x folder in the same folder where your .py file is.
   Use pathlib to be sure your path is correct.

```
from pathlib import Path
path = Path(__file__).parent.joinpath('reddit_vectors-1.1.0')
s2v.from_disk(path)
```

2. If you still get the error, delete your reddit_vectors-x.x.x folder and re untar/unzip the original reddit_vectors-x.x.x.tar.gz or reddit_vectors-x.x.x.zip